# Is the holy grail still important or is that history?

Tags: html, css

Before HTML5, a lot of effort was made to have the main content early in the HTML source, mainly before columns that would now be marked as `aside` today. (The optimal way for three column layouts was the [Holy Grail](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)).

There were two reasons to do this:

- SEO: Earlier content counted as more important for search engines
- Accessibility: Show the important content first for those that view the content without CSS

With HTML5, we can solve this problem with markup. We can markup a column on the left with `aside` and the main content with `main`. We could dump the holy grail, use `table-cell` for the CSS effect of three equally high columns and HTML5 markup to tell search engines/screen readers which part the main content is.

**Is the holy grail still important for SEO/accessibility or is that history?** 
Is it important for any other reason?

Most of the time Mobile seems to be the answer. In mobile layouts, content order matters. So I adapt my question:

**Is the holy grail still the state of the art for multi column layouts?**

PS: I know flexbox is coming. I'm asking with some backwards compatibility in mind.

Comment: *"Is it important for any other reason?"* - I think at least the Accessibility reason still applies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info)

Comment: @Quentin I can adapt the question

Comment: @Teetrinker — Then adapt it. Try not to leave it in a state where it would be considered "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @Quentin changed it.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.